# Unclear work training assignment, looking for some outside guidence

Tags: python

I'm doing a training assignment for my employer through a sponsored third party service.  So far a lot of the assignments have needed massive fixes (they are meant to just be re-typed and run but are rather broken) and I've managed it. However, this one has me by the hair and I can't begin to figure out how to do it.  I thought maybe argv import at first but that doesn't seem like the right answer in my head.

```
import cmath

a = complex(arg[0], arg[1])
b = complex(arg[2], arg[3])
c = a + b

print ("\n Addition of two numbers is: ", c)
c = a - b
print ("\n Subtraction of two numbers is: ", c)
c = a * b
print ("\n Multiplication of two numbers is: ", c)
d = a / b
print ("\n Division of two numbers is: ", c)
```

Any thoughts would be great on this ... and seriously I apologize but I'm stumped and the assignments provide no direction.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: What is `arg`? I assume an array...can you post a sample of the data contained within it?

Comment: change that last `d = a / b` to `c = a / b`

Comment: "maybe argv import at first" -> is it `arg` or `argv` in the code? If it's _not_ `argv`, you'll have to define `arg` yourself, which isn't "fixing others' code", but "writing your own code".

Comment: If you're looking for getting command line arguments, you do `sys.argv` for that, not just `argv`.

Comment: @Jack Bashford - NameError: name 'arg' is not defined.  That is also all the data the assignment provides.

Comment: So...maybe define it?

Comment: Do you know what this code is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your statement above guessing about `argv` I think you meant `sys.argv`. so here is a solution to your problem

```
from sys import argv
if len(argv) < 5:  # program name + 4 numbers obtained from the user.
    print("Provide 4 numbers")
    exit()

print(argv)  # first argument is program file name. so you need to start by index 1 not 0.
a = complex(int(argv[1]), int(argv[2]))
b = complex(int(argv[3]), int(argv[4]))
c = a + b

print("\n Addition of two numbers is: ", c)
c = a - b
print("\n Subtraction of two numbers is: ", c)
c = a * b
print("\n Multiplication of two numbers is: ", c)
d = a / b
print("\n Division of two numbers is: ", d)
```

argv first element in the array is the filename containing the program.